# Why no volatile?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, static-variables, java-memory-model

I have a discussion with a colleague about this code:

```
public final class ShutdownHookRegistration {

/**
 * Global shutdown flag
 */
private static boolean isServerShutdown = false;

private ShutdownHookRegistration() {
    // empty
}

/**
 * Returns the current value of the global shutdown flag
 *
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isServerShutdown() {
    return isServerShutdown;
}

/**
 * Registration if shutdown hooks
 */
public static void registerShutdownHooks() {
    /**
     * 1. Shutdown hook to set the shutdown flag
     */
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(setGlobalShutdownFlag());
}

/**
 * Sets the global static is shutdown flag which can be checked by other processes.
 *
 * @return
 */
private static Thread setGlobalShutdownFlag() {
    return new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            isServerShutdown = true;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":shutdown set");
        }
    };
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Flag set:" + ShutdownHookRegistration.isServerShutdown);
    Thread t1 = ShutdownHookRegistration.setGlobalShutdownFlag();
    Thread t2 = new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            while (!ShutdownHookRegistration.isServerShutdown) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Flag set:" + ShutdownHookRegistration.isServerShutdown);
            }
        }
    };
    t2.start();
    t1.start();
}
```

Output:

```
Thread-1 Flag set:false
Thread-1 Flag set:false
Thread-1 Flag set:false
Thread-1 Flag set:false
[..]
Thread-0:shutdown set
```

I thought without volatile this code would run in an infinite loop, but somehow it will always terminate.

Can someone explain why here no volatile is necessary?

Comment: When reading answers below, remember that the Java language gives JVM implementors some freedom in implementing certain features.  That allows implementors to get the best possible performance on any given architecture.  What it mans for app developers is:  If you want your program to run on a particular JVM on a particular configuration of a particular OS, you can test for that, but if you want your application to run _everywhere_, then you should obey all of the rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short there is two reasons, your loop has a memory barrier and even if it didn't it's not run long enough to be optimised/compiled in a matter which need volatile.

The key is here

```
while (!ShutdownHookRegistration.isServerShutdown) {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Flag set:" + ShutdownHookRegistration.isServerShutdown);
}
```

System.out.println is `synchronized` which means there is a read/write barrier in each iteration.

```
// from the java 6 source
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

In the x64 JVM, once you lock one object you place a memory barrier which protects all memory accesses.

Additionally, this slows down your code by 10,000x or more, so that it doesn't run long enough to get compiled (and optimised in a matter which required `volatile`) It would take looping in the order of 10,000 times before this code is compiled.

Comment: System.out.println is synchronized which means there is a read/write barrier in each iteration. --> Did not check it. Thanks :)

Comment: @IncredibleLou it is a little obscure. I had been looking at code like# this for years before I realised this was one reason it definitively wouldn't be needed in this type of loop.

Answer (score 4):

Marking a field [`volatile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4)...

> ...ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the variable ([§17.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)).

*Not* marking it `volatile` doesn't necessarily mean other threads won't see the changed value *eventually*, just that they may well keep seeing the old value for a while, as the old value can be cached for the thread (since it's not `volatile`). But that doesn't mean their cached value won't be updated at *some* point. Just that that may be at some remove (e.g., delay) from when the value is changed by another thread.

If you want the change observed proactively, make the field `volatile`, but note that that will impact the threads reading/writing it (whether that's a problem is another thing entirely).

Answer (score -1):

Every thread gets a copy of the variable **isServerShutdown**, the JVM can every not determinated time refresh and update that value, many apps will work, many dont, others will work when you add another statements in the run method...

you are just getting lucky, if you need the app to work as it should YOU HAVE TO USE VOLATILE VARIABLE.